# Create a transaction to display the Sales order and its subsequent document flow with the status in ALV format

Tags: abap, sap-erp

What is subsequent document flow in SAP ABAP?

How to display the flow in SAP ABAP using sales order?

How to display the existing sales order details?

Comment: Do you want to program it comletely new in abap or use standard transactions to check this data?

Comment: Do you use S/4HANA? If yes, your question should be tagged [tag:s4hana].

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

As the question is rather general I would give some starting hint points.

First of all there is a certain sequence of documents in Sales and Distribution, which reflects the corresponding business processes. A typical general document chain could be: Inquiry -> Quotation -> Sales order -> Delivery -> Shipment -> Invoice, etc., where the following documents are created based on the previous ones. This document sequence could be reflected and implemented in SAP as needed in accordance with concrete business requirements.

The **document flow** shows how far the sales document has been processed. It consists of the sequence of related previous and subsequent documents in a relation to the selected document used as a starting point.

To implement your requirement you can start with a simple report (additionally assigning a transaction code to it if necessary), ask for a sales document number as a parameter and afterwards use BAPIs delivered from SAP to dynamically read the necessary data and display it afterwards as required. (Note: of course it is always possible to read the data directly from DB-tables also, but it is usually much more verbose and requires a good knowledge of the underlying database model).

To start with you can try the following BAPIs:

- `BAPISDORDER_GETDETAILEDLIST` to read the sales order details
- `RV_ORDER_FLOW_INFORMATION` to read the document flow

To test BAPIs and check what data they return, use transaction `SE37` to call these function modules (use can also use this transaction to search for other available FMs in the system).
To find some sales order numbers for testing, use, for example,  transaction `VA03` to find one.

To create an ALV list there are several possibilities, but the best option in this case is to use an object oriented approach starting with `CL_SALV_TABLE` class.